# How to delete older versions with a certain condition which were created by paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

I want to delete the old entries of an entity in the 'versions' table with the following conditions

1. First, It should be sorted by the recently modified
2. I would like to remove all records which have more than 10 entries for an entity (i.e. a single row)

Is there a query which I can use to delete this.

My current proposal is to remove such versions as follows, but I would prefer if there is a query which allows you to remove all older versions based across entities:-

```
entities.each do |entity|
   versions = entity.versions.order('created_at DESC')
   if versions.count > 10
     #deleting all remaining versions except the 10 entries
   end
end
```